# Заполнить массив объектов Image

Tags: изображения, swing

Здравствуйте!
Почему не работает данный код? Возможно, нужно делать это по-другому...
Задача: в файле animation содержатся картинки, мне нужно элементам массива img_mas присвоить эти картинки.

```
for ( i  = 0 ; i<img_mas.length; i++){
            try {
                img_mas[i] = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("С:/myfiles/animation/.png"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Что-то путь у Вас странный

```
С:/myfiles/animation/.png
```

Вы уверены?)

Comment: Да,есть ошибка )
C:/myfiles/animation.png;
всё равно не проходит
ошибка: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!